# What is the difference between isTrigger, originalEvent and isTrusted in Javascript Event?

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

What is the difference between isTrigger, originalEvent and isTrusted in Javascript Event? Which one should I choose for detecting user-triggered actions?

I am using Vue JS and when data is being fetched from API, the value of input is updated by data fetched from api.

```
data() {
    return {
        value: "",
        operator: "",
    }
},
```

When I am trying update value of operator or value:

```
var f = this.searchFilters.filter((c) => c.attribute_name == this.column.attribute)

this.value = f[0].value
this.operator = f[0].operator
```

The event triggers and the app behaves very differently, to solve this I have used `e.originalEvent` to fix the problem. But I can find more options to fix this issue and they are following

1. e.isTrigger
2. e.originalEvent
3. e.isTrusted

Can anybody please explain the basic difference between these properties?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve a different problem. What is the problem at hand?

Comment: @Halcyon If I am trying to update the value of input by programmatically, JavaScript is throwing event, but I don't want js to through event when I update the value of input by programmatically.

Comment: I don't think changing the value normally triggers any event. What event are you seeing?

Comment: The update function triggers!

Comment: If you do `input.value = "foo"` it wont trigger the `onchange` callback.

Comment: I am using Vue Js and it triggers `onchange` callback on changing value of data.

Comment: It must be calling `dispatchEvent()` itself, it's not done automatically by JS.

Comment: Here is the screencast for the problem. The data is being fetched from api and set to input fields and then event triggers! https://www.screencast.com/t/Nhlio6iEstSY

Comment: You can check after 27 seconds, the data is loaded and the event triggers and you can see a message: Your filter has changed.

Comment: @Ilyaskarim link doesn't work. Also it would be way easier if you post your code, in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) way, preferably.

Comment: @yuriy636 The link is updated now.